# How to get all available shipping methods programmatically in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm using magento C.E 1.7. I use all shipping methods of magento and I'm viewing only one shipping method in the front end, which has higher priority. I'm using table rate shipping for some countries.

I wanted to add **special fixed shipping price** for some products when they shipped to that countries only. So that, I added new shipping method namely '**flat rate per product**', by using a new module.

Based on this module, a text box is added to all the products in admin to specify the special shipping price. If I filled this field with some value, It considers it as a special shipping price. And if not filled it, it will be considered as special shipping price is $0.

So I have given least priority in the sort order for this shipping method to avoid this method from viewing on front end when products without special shipping price and products with special shipping price both are added into the cart.

So that, If only the special shipping priced product is added to the cart, It shows only table rate shipping method  in front end.

I checked the code in availble.phtml. There is a foreach loop to proceed with available shipping methods. I need to check the availability of the '**flat rate per product**' and it's price value for the product before start of loop execution.

I tried to get all the values of the array. But I could not. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please share some code so we get better idea of how you are trying to do that

Comment: you must go through how to make a shipping mehtod.
your problem solution is here please read, definately it will helps you . http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/

Answer (score -1):

**you can use this code:**

```
<?php 
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
$shipMethods = array();
foreach ($methods as $shippigCode=>$shippingModel) 
{
    $shippingTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/title');
    $shipMethods[$shippigCode] = $shippingTitle;
}
return $shipMethods;
?>
```

Comment: This only retrieves active shipping carriers, not methods